# after system resets environment value is lost

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

```
   int abcd()
   {
    int temp1=0;

    char *env=NULL;
    env=getenv("ENVIRONMENT");
    sscanf(env,"%d",&temp1);
    temp1=temp1+1;
    printf("%d",temp1);
    sprintf(env,"%d",temp1);
    setenv("ENVIRONMENT",env,0);
    }
```

Initially i have manually set the ENVIRONMENT to 0 by using `export ENVIRONMENT=0`. Now this code will set the `ENVIRONMENT` to 0. Now when the system will restart I want that `ENVIROMENT` value should be 1 but again the value is 0 only. How to retain the value even if system restarts.

Comment: write them to your shell profile (for example ~/.bash_proflle). setenv() will change environment variables for current process only.

Answer (score 1):

Add the value of environment variable to the user `bashrc` or global `bashrc` by adding

```
export ENVIRONMENT=0
```

to `/etc/bashrc`(needs `sudo`) or `~/.bashrc`

After your program changes the environment variable,make it write/edit to any one of these files.

Comment: can u exp;lain in more detail how to do this

Comment: use standard file operations,say `fprintf`, to write the string `export ENVIRONMENT=0` to the files mentioned.With every further run,traverse till end of the line and edit/replace the line.